# python call to boto3.client.create_data_source_from_s3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, boto3

I'm trying to use AWS Machine Learning batch processes from a python project.  I'm using boto3.  I am getting this failure message in the response.

> There was an error trying to parse the schema: \'Can not deserialize
>   instance of boolean out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source:
>   java.io.StringReader@60618eb4; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference
>   chain:
>   com.amazon.eml.dp.recordset.SchemaPojo["dataFileContainsHeader"])\

The .csv file I am using works.  I know this because it worked through the console process.

Here is my code; it is a function within a django model which holds the url to the file to be processed (input_file):

```
    def create_data_source_from_s3(self):
        attributes = []
        attribute = { "fieldName": "Var1", "fieldType": "CATEGORICAL" }
        attributes.append(attribute)
        attribute = { "fieldName": "Var2", "fieldType": "CATEGORICAL" }
        attributes.append(attribute)
        attribute = { "fieldName": "Var3", "fieldType": "NUMERIC" }
        attributes.append(attribute)
        attribute = { "fieldName": "Var4", "fieldType": "CATEGORICAL" }
        attributes.append(attribute)
        attribute = { "fieldName": "Var5", "fieldType": "CATEGORICAL" }
        attributes.append(attribute)
        attribute = { "fieldName": "Var6", "fieldType": "CATEGORICAL" }
        attributes.append(attribute)

        dataSchema = {}
        dataSchema['version'] = '1.0'
        dataSchema['dataFormat'] = 'CSV'
        dataSchema['attributes'] = attributes
        dataSchema["targetFieldName"] = "Var6"
        dataSchema["dataFileContainsHeader"] = True,
        json_data = json.dumps(dataSchema)

        client = boto3.client('machinelearning', region_name=settings.region, aws_access_key_id=settings.aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=settings.aws_secret_access_key)
        #create a datasource
        return client.create_data_source_from_s3(
            DataSourceId=self.input_file.name,
            DataSourceName=self.input_file.name,
            DataSpec={
                'DataLocationS3': 's3://' + settings.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME + '/' + self.input_file.name,
                'DataSchema': json_data,
            },
            ComputeStatistics=True
            )
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the comma

```
  dataSchema["dataFileContainsHeader"] = True,
```

This is causing Python to think that you are adding a tuple. So your dataSchema actually contains (True, )

and your output looks like this

```
{"dataFileContainsHeader": [true], "attributes": [{"fieldName": "Var1", "fieldType": "CATEGORICAL"}, {"fieldName": "Var2", "fieldType": "CATEGORICAL"}, {"fieldName": "Var3", "fieldType": "NUMERIC"}, {"fieldName": "Var4", "fieldType": "CATEGORICAL"}, {"fieldName": "Var5", "fieldType": "CATEGORICAL"}, {"fieldName": "Var6", "fieldType": "CATEGORICAL"}], "version": "1.0", "dataFormat": "CSV", "targetFieldName": "Var6"}
```

AWS is instead expecting something like this

```
"dataFileContainsHeader": true
```